# How to read/write from a data file in C++

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

I'm having a problem reading from a binary file (*.dat) using the .read(reinterpret_cast  (&x),sizeof(x)) command but there is always an error about the existence of the file even when the file exist or has been created successfully. Here is the code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;


 struct x{
  char name[10],pass[10];
 };


 int main()
 {
   x x1,x2;
   fstream inout;
   inout.open("test.dat" ,ios::binary);
   if(!inout)
   {
      cout<<"Error";
      exit(1);
   }
   cout<<"Enter your name:";
   cin>>x1.name;
   inout.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&x1.name), sizeof(x1));
   cout<<"Enter your name:";
   cin>>x1.pass;
   inout.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&x1.pass), sizeof(x1));
   while(inout.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&x2.name), sizeof(x1)))
   {
      cout<<x2.name;//here is my problem cannot read!!
   }
   inout.close();
 }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: There is  no error, i'm not getting any thing on the screen!

Comment: Is `test.dat` a pre-existing file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `std:flush` after your write operations.

```
// ... Write x1.name and x1.pass

inout << std::flush;

// ... Read x2.name in while loop.

inout.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your output to the file. 
First you are writing the struct x1 to the file where only the name field is filled

```
inout.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&x1.name), sizeof(x1));
```

and afterwards:

```
inout.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&x1.pass), sizeof(x1));
```

You start writing from the address of x1.pass but you are writing sizeof(x1) bytes.
sizeof(x1) is 20 here but its only 10 bytes from the start of x1.pass to the end of the struct, so you are writing 10 bytes of unknown data from the stack into your file. 
So this is the first thing that your file may not contain what you expect it to contain.

The next thing is that after writing your data the stream is sitting at the end of the file and you try to read from there. You have to move the position back to the beginning of the stream to read the stuff you just wrote. For example use:

```
inout.seekg(std::ios::beg);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mess with read and write to the same stream, you'd rather use flush or file positioning functions.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h58eac.aspx):

> When a basic_fstream object is used to perform file I/O, although the underlying buffer contains separately designated positions for reading and writing, the current input and current output positions are tied together, and therefore, reading some data moves the output position.

[GNU Stdlib](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html):

> As you can see, ‘+’ requests a stream that can do both input and output. When using such a stream, you must call fflush (see Stream Buffering) or a file positioning function such as fseek (see File Positioning) when switching from reading to writing or vice versa. Otherwise, internal buffers might not be emptied properly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading into raw C-style arrays from an input stream is not as idiomatic as a simple call to `operator>>()`. You also have to prevent buffer overruns by keeping track of the both the bytes allocated for the buffer, and the bytes being read into the buffer.

Reading into the buffer can be done by using the input stream method `getline()`. The following example shows the extraction into `x1.name`; the same would be done for `x1.path`:

```
if (std::cin.getline(x1.name, sizeof(x1.name))) {

}
```

The second argument is the maximum number of bytes to be read. It is useful in that the stream won't write pass the allocated bounds of the array. The next thing to do is just write it to the file as you have done:

```
if (std::cin.getline(x1.name, sizeof(x1.name))) {
    inout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x1.name), std::cin.gcount());
}
```

`std::cin.gcount()` is the number of characters that were read from the input stream. It is a much more reliable alternative to `sizeof(x1.name)` in that it returns the number of characters *written*, not the characters allotted.

Now, bidirectional file streams are a bit tricky. They have be coordinated in the right way. As explained in the other answers, bidirectional file streams (or `std::fstream`s) share a joint buffer for both input and output. The position indicators that mark positions in the input and output sequence are both affected by any input and output operations that may occur. As such, the file stream position has to be "moved" back before performing input. This can be done by either a call to `seekg()` or `seekp()`. Either will suffice since, as I said, the position indicators are bound to each other:

```
if (std::cin.getline(x1.pass, sizeof(x1.pass))) {
    inout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x1.pass), std::cin.gcount());
    inout.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
}
```

Notice how this was done after the extraction into `x1.pass`. We can't do it after `x1.name` because we would be overwriting the stream on the second call to `write()`.

---

As you can see, extracting into raw C-style arrays isn't pretty, you have to manage more things than you should. Fortunately, C++ comes to the rescue with their standard string class `std::string`. Use this for more efficient I/O:

Make both `name` and `pass` standard C++ strings (`std::string`) instead of raw C-arrays. This allows you pass in the size as the second argument to your `read()` and `write()` calls:

```
#include <string>

struct x {
    std::string name;
    std::string pass;
};

// ...
if (std::cin >> x1.name) {
    inout.write(x1.name.data(), x1.name.size());
}

if (std::cin >> x1.pass) {
    inout.write(x1.name.data(), x1.name.size());
    inout.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
}
```

`std::string` allows us to leverage its dynamic nature and its capacity for maintaining the size of the buffer. We no longer have to use `getline()` but now a simple call to `operator>>()` and an `if()` check.

This was not possible before, but now that we're using `std::string` we can also combine both extractions to achieve the following:

```
if (std::cout << "Enter your name: " && std::cin >> x1.name &&
    std::cout << "Enter your pass: " && std::cin >> x1.pass) {
    inout.write(x1.name.data(), x1.name.size());
    inout.write(x1.pass.data(), x1.pass.size());
    inout.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
}
```

And finally, the last extraction would simply be this:

```
while (inout >> x2.name)
{
    std::cout << x2.name;
}
```